# CSS Grid Repeat Pattern

Tags: html, css, css-grid

my code looks like the below. It works but is very repetitive. Does anyone know how to make this cleaner? I think we are supposed to use repeat or nth child?

[image]

I'm a bit new to html and css, excuse me for the bad code. Thank you!

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.item1 {
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 8;
}

.item2 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}
.item3 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 6;
}
.item4 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-start: 6;
  grid-column-end: 8;
}
.item5 {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}
.item6 {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 6;
}
.item7 {
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 6;
  grid-column-end: 8;
}
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

1. First split common styles and individual styles . Then use Class for
   common and ID for individual.

The difference between an ID and a class is that an ID can be used to identify one element, whereas a class can be used to identify more than one. In the CSS, a class selector is a name preceded by a full stop (“.”) and an ID selector is a name preceded by a hash character (“#”).

2. If you have repetitive patterns , use repeat()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat

3. If you have specific logic or formula, you can use nth-child(n) where n can be a number, a keyword, or a formula

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: I see! I'll go ahead and try this out. Thank you!

Comment: @yuehh Did any answer help you? if so consider accepting any answer so that people will stop answering.

Answer (score 0):

While you could manage this with nth-child, using classes is a cleaner way.

You require a **twelve** column grid at minimum, as you have elements that span 1/3, 1/2 and all columns.

**You can't split an 8 column grid into thirds.**

So, just apply classes to specify how many columns each div should span as follows:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
  gap: .25em;
  margin: 1em;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.span-12 {
  grid-column: span 12;
}

.span-6 {
  grid-column: span 6;
}

.span-4 {
  grid-column: span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item span-12">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item span-4">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item span-4">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item span-4">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item span-4">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item span-4">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item span-4">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item span-6">Item 8</div>
  <div class="item span-6">Item 9</div>
  <div class="item span-12">Item 10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  grid-column: span 2;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 20px;
}

.grid-container>div:nth-child(9n + 1) {
  grid-column: span 6;
}

.grid-container>div:nth-child(9n - 1),
.grid-container>div:nth-child(9n) {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```